# ConTeXt: Block vs Environment vs Group

Tags: context, semantics

I've seen these all used somewhat interchangeably. What's the difference?

*edit*:
I've seen many `\start..stop` blocks referred sometimes referred to as environment. For example the *verbatim environment* for `\start...stoptyping` block. Some are even ambiguously named like `\start...startsectionblockenvironment`. Then there's the big picture. Is `\start...stoptext` an environment or a block? *Excursions* says this in section 40.5, *Floating Blocks*:

> A block in CONTEXT is a text element, for example a table or a figure
>   that you can process in a special way. You have already seen the use
>   of `\placefigure` and `\placetable`. These are both examples of floating
>   blocks.

Where does that leave regular paragraphs? From the wiki I get the sense that colloquially blocks imply 'more' vmode whereas environments can be either vmode or hmode. So `\start..stoptextbackground` is an environment rather than a block because it can be used inline?

What do you call a clump of text that forms a semantic element, a higher-level view than characters, glue and boxes? On a tangent I came across TeX 'groups' and, knowing nothing of them, decided perhaps they could be related to this question.

Comment: Could you please give an example for each (what you refer to)? If I hear environment in ConTeXt I am thinking about environment files (as opposed to a LaTeX context where I would think of environment macros) which have nothing to do with grouping (which I would associate with TeX groups).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the manual a `\start...\stop` pair is usually called *environment*.  I don't think ConTeXt has a notion of a *block*.  There is the concept of `sectionblock` but that is just another name for sectioning level (chapter, section, subsection, etc.).

Taking the excursion as a reference for terminology is a bit dangerous, because it was not written by Hans.  Therefore the phrases used in there do not necessarily reflect the names in the ConTeXt core.  I would not call it “floating blocks” but “floating objects” or just “floats”.  [It's in the details](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/details.pdf) just calls them “floats”.

For clumps of text the regular typographic classification applies.  Glyphs make up words, words make up lines, lines make up paragraphs, paragraphs make up sections (or `sectionblocks` in ConTeXt-speak), sections make up the document.

TeX's grouping is related to environments.  Usually environments for a group, i.e. the contents of a `\start...\stop` pair are enclosed in a lexical group ([exceptio probat regulam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule)).

Now `\start...\stoptext` takes a special place.  `\starttext` does *not* start a new level grouping and therefore `\stoptext` does not end the group.  This has to do with the engine internals as typesetting a long document within a lexical group would overflow TeX's memory.  There are other environments which do not form a group but they are rare.

Comment: Oh, groups are formed by `{`,`}`! Where do itemgroups fall into this typographic classification, in relation to lines and paragraphs? And paragraphs and sectionblocks are both groups?

Comment: *itemgroups and other non-paragraph environments.

Comment: @user19087 An item in an itemgroup is just a paragraph with indentation and a symbol in front of the first line.  In Plain TeX, the definiton of `\item` is actually just `\par\hang\textindent` which shows more clearly that it is just a regular paragraph with hanging indentation.

Comment: So do the regular typographic classifications form implicit groups, i.e. words, lines, paragraphs, and sections, i.e. is it groups "all the way down"?